# ALFA usb wifi dongle not showing up in ifconfig

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

Recently built a PC and everything's working fine except for the wifi dongle. I was told to get a PCI wifi card, but the slots aren't far enough on motherboard, and connecting a graphics card takes up all the space.

So I bought an ALFA USB WiFi dongle. In the CD that came with it, it's mentioned that it's a rtl8188EUS RealTek chip. Since the driver they provided in the disk didn't compile (maybe because it was for Linux 4.1, and I'm on 5.x), I tried installing these drivers:

- https://quickreflex.github.io/rtl8188eus/ - builds fine. Installed too. Loaded with `modprobe`. Using `dmseg | tail`, I'm sure that the correct driver is loaded for the usb dongle. But it doesn't show anywhere in `ifconfig`
- https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus - same with this. Interface doesn't show in `ifconfig`

Is there anything I'm missing or doing wrong? What can I do to get this working.

Comment: try with `ifconfig -a` and `iwconfig`

Comment: @cmak.fr no luck, `ifconfig -a` lists same interfaces as `ifconfig`. and `iwconfig` says none of interfaces has wireless extensions.

Comment: if the good driver is loaded, ifconfig -a should show the nic... what gives `lsmod | grep 8188` ? (fyi the `rtl8188eu` module is bundled with ubuntu but there can be an issue with networkmanager that cant see it loaded)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the drivers I was testing were the wrong ones. Thanks to [u/XFM2z8BH](https://www.reddit.com/user/XFM2z8BH/) on reddit, I found the right one.

Just had to do this to get it running:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone git://github.com/ulli-kroll/rtl8188fu
cd rtl8188fu
make
sudo make installfw
sudo modprobe cfg80211
sudo insmod rtl8188fu.ko
```